# ASP.NET MVC Web Site & WCF Web Service - Sharing functionalities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, architecture

I have the following situation: I have to create a website and a web service that will *`share a part of the functionalities`*.

This is why I do not want to write code twice.

I have thought of the following architecture:

**MyApp.BusinessLogic** --> here we save the DataModels to the database

**MyApp.DataAccess** -> DataModels & Entity & mapping

---

**MyApp.UI.Models** -> ViewModels

**MyApp.UI.ServiceLayer** -> Acceses the Business Logic, creates the UI ViewModels for the website, and transforms the ViewModels back into DataModels for saving with the help of the BusinessLogic Layer

**MyApp.WebSite**

---

**MyApp.WS.Models** - >Ws Models, these will be the objects passed between the client and the WS

**MyApp.WS.ServiceLayer** -> Accesses the business Logic, creates the WS Models for the web service, and transfoms the WS.Models back into DataModels for saving with the help of the  BusinessLogic Layer

**MyApp.WebService**

---

Is the architecture overkill ? What problems will I encounter ? Will I have problems with the controllers in the ASP.NET MVC website ?

Answer (score 1):

When I design my applications I do it like this. My only issue is the dull copying of models to view models. The best way to overcome this to use AutoMapper.

I would though create some unittests because there is a high risk of breaking the app when changing the services (and visa versa). Unit testing would tell you that early on.

Comment: I have thought  of the Automapper as well. The unit testing is another  issue.

Answer (score 0):

Define basically :)

If you want to reduce the code usage, why not create your service, then just consume it in the app?

So if you would have something like...

Foo.DataAccess
-Foo.BusinessLogic
--Foo.ServiceLayer

Then have that referenced by:
Foo.WebService (including models for view/update... but probably simplify externally)

Then use
Foo.WebApp
and have this consuming Foo.Webservice to make the data calls on it's behalf

Having UI and web service models increases your code duplication, you could use something like Fluent validation to let the service handle your validation, and enhance the basic validation system.

Comment: Having duplicate models looks good to me. There will be situations where you want them to be different. Furthermore, the service are only proxy's to the business layer so I see no use in consuming them in the app.

Comment: I have used this  technique of consuming the webservice with the webapp and it's hell to debug.  Not doing it again. Plus, if I want to add extra functionalities to the webapp later I will face difficulties.

Comment: @DragosDurlut Having the common access system makes it easier to test, I haven't ran into issues debugging this sort of structure but on a higher level of complexity I can see it could be difficult.

I asked how basically the same the code was to be as if you want to add extra functionality to a webapp why wouldn't you expose it to the service? It increases the risk of differing code and doesn't follow DRY principles

Comment: That is true @Patrick, however by exposing the standard models in the service you can adapt or convert the models in your web app so that you have view/create/edit models there that convert to ones suitable for use on the service.  

If you are set on a duplicated servicelayer to connect to the business layer the webapp could have a pseudo service layer that simply converts to/from models for the web service

Comment: @finnman The problem is that at some point in time,  the  website will have extra functionalities from the WS. Trust me, it  was hard to debug. plus,  you might want to  write the website now and the WS later.